# Jenkins single git warehouse Multiple project

Tags: jenkins

project code structure:

```
$ git clone git@git-server:/data/git/project.git

$ tree -L 1 project
.
├── pushServer
├── README
├── redis_cloud_task
├── Time
├── access
├── business
├── business_client
├── common
├── parent
└── web

$ tree -L 1 project/pushServer/
pushServer/
├── cert
├── config
├── lib
├── pom.xml
├── resource
├── src
└── WebRoot
```

How should I configure them in jenkins? They are all java web projects.

For example, when configuring common projects, configuring git sources in jenkins can only be configured as git@git-server:/data/git/project.git.

[maven config 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/733kB.png)

[maven config 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23JlS.png)

build

```
Building in workspace /data/srv/tomcat/jenkins/workspace/common
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@git-server:/data/git/project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git-server:/data/git/project.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@git-server:/data/git/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse origin/${branch_tag}^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse ${branch_tag}^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```